# How to configure concurrency in .NET Core Web API?

Tags: concurrency, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

In the old WCF days, you had control over service concurrency via `MaxConcurrentCalls` setting. `MaxConcurrentCalls` defaulted to 16 concurrent calls but you could raise or lower that value based upon your needs.

How do you control server side concurrency in .NET Core Web API?  We probably need to limit it in our case as too many concurrent requests can impede overall server performance.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ASP.NET Core application concurrency is handled by its [web server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/). For example:

#### Kestrel

```cs
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(options => options.ThreadCount = 8)
```

It is not recommended to set Kestrel thread count to a large value like `1K` due to Kestrel async-based implementation.

More info: [Is Kestrel using a single thread for processing requests like Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948857/is-kestrel-using-single-thread-for-processing-requests-like-node-js)

New `Limits` property has been [introduced](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/06/28/introducing-asp-net-core-2-0-preview-2/) in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Preview 2.

> You can now add limits for the following:
>
> 1. Maximum Client Connections
> 2. Maximum Request Body Size
> 3. Maximum Request Body Data Rate

For example:

```cs
.UseKestrel(options =>
{
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
}
```

#### IIS

When Kestrel runs behind a reverse proxy you could tune the proxy itself. For example, you could configure IIS application pool in `web.config` or in `aspnet.config`:

```xml
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <applicationPool
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000"
        maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0"
        requestQueueLimit="5000" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Of course **Nginx** and **Apache** have their own concurrency settings.

Comment: If i add changes to aspnet.config, how to apply them? Restart server? Restart iis? Recycle apppool?

Comment: Does anyone know what the behaviour of the Kestrel web host is when a request comes in and the server is already running the maximum number of threads?