# How to set a net core application on IIS not to receive many requests

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, .net-core

I have a net core API that does heavy calculations, and for these reasons, I would like to set a limit to the requests.

My first attempt is to deploy this API to the local IIS and then set the queue length to 10.
But then when I call the endpoint from a console app with 11 requests, the API process the requests.

A second attempt is to add in the API a web config file with something like this

```
    <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <applicationPool
            maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU="5000"
            maxConcurrentThreadsPerCPU="0"
            requestQueueLimit="5000" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

but the problem is, I have a warning in the application pool element with the message :

> the element system. web has invalid child element applicationpool

Has someone any idea how to set limits of the requests in the IIS for my API?

Comment: Googling around shows me that the `applicationPool` is supported since IIS 7 only, what IIS version do you use? Also for asp.net core, you have more options to configure this, check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44391268/how-to-configure-concurrency-in-net-core-web-api

Comment: @KingKing thank you for the response, my iis version is 10.0