# .Net Core processes one request at a time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

My .Net Core app processes one request at time. That seems that .net core is single threaded. I am using .Net Core 2.0 and have enabled libuv and given options for multithreads but seems like its multithread for one single request. how i am running my host -

```
  var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseLibuv(opt=>opt.ThreadCount=4)
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())                
            .UseStartup<Startup>()                
            .Build();

        host.Run();
```

and if i put logging my custom middleware and controller I can see that process one request at time and keep the client waiting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Kestrel using a single thread for processing requests like Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948857/is-kestrel-using-a-single-thread-for-processing-requests-like-node-js)