# UseLibuv option gone after changing Microsoft.aspnetcore.all to Microsoft.NETCore.App in .net core 2.1.6

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

I am using asp.net core 2.1.6 
I have just changed my Microsoft.aspnetcore.all to Microsoft.NETCore.App as publishing the web api project is making too much size.
In my code i were using use UseLibuv(o => o.ThreadCount = 1000) to set minmum thread count

```
public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<StartupShutdownHandler>()
                //.UseLibuv(o => o.ThreadCount = 1000)  
                ;
```

Now this option is not coming. How can i set min threads now like old one

It is bit related to 
[Is Kestrel using a single thread for processing requests like Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40948857/is-kestrel-using-a-single-thread-for-processing-requests-like-node-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UseLibuv`, it's under `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv` package, you could try to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv` from nuget.

Comment: Would there be any performance different between using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Libuv` and not?

Comment: @mugi that would be up to your testing. Microsoft claims their implementation is faster, but considering the history, it might be worth it to do you own independent testing. I am currently testing a high load high throughput scenario, and will let you know my result here.